# How to insert the character "•" present in suggestions e.g. \begin{•}, \section{•} (Texmaker)

Tags: symbols, texmaker

The character I refer to is a bullet appearing in the suggested command which one can navigete using Tab, i.e. if the line is \begin{•}[•], by pressing Tab if the cursor is before the command, the first bullet will be selected and after pressing Tab again the second one will be selected.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is hardcoded within the editor, maybe there is a file you can edit to add own commands. This has nothing to do with LaTeX or active characters though.

Comment: Or are you looking for `\bullet`? Needs  math mode.

Comment: I don't understand this question...

Comment: winedt uses ASCII 127 (hex7F) here, probably texstudio uses the same. How you can input it depends a lot on your editor, keyboard, OS. In winedt I can use ctrl+alt+space.  On a keyboard with numeric keys I would try alt+127.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to insert a custom command that is auto completed by Texmaker offering the `•` to jump to it by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>.

To add such a custom command, navigate to `User --> Customize Completion` and a window like the following will open (might look different in a more recent version of Texmaker):
[image]

On the left side you can see a list of special caracters you can add to achieve a certain functionality. In this case `@` adds the placeholder `•` as you can see on the right side of the window.

---

If you instead want to add this symbol into your text, you might be more interested in the comments from [Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418363/how-to-insert-the-character-present-in-suggestions-e-g-begin-section#comment1046563_418363) and [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418363/how-to-insert-the-character-present-in-suggestions-e-g-begin-section#comment1046577_418363).

Comment: Thanks a lot!, yes, what I wanted was to be able to insert the a placeholder.

Comment: @Alex -- welcome to tex.sx.  the accepted way of saying thanks for an answer that works is to (1) upvote it, and (2) click on the check mark that appears below the vote counter.